# How to do database migration using python script?

Tags: python, django

is it possible to do migration from python script?

I am trying to use django on Heliohost where there is no shell but I can use python script.

```
something like

from django import shell
shell.main(['mysite/manage.py', 'migrate'])
```

**Edit**

Using input from @Shadow, I tried putting this code in views.py file

```
def migrate(request):
    django.setup()
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command("migrate", interactive=False)
    return HttpResponse("Final Migration Successful")
```

Then visited the url mapped to migrate which returned "Final Migration Successful"

then I tried the database like

```
from .models import Question


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Gives me error:

```
(1146, "Table 'usr_mydb.polls_question' doesn't exist")
```

***From Django Tutorial:***

Bypassing manage.py

If you’d rather not use manage.py, no problem. Just set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to mysite.settings, start a plain Python shell, and set up Django:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
```

If this raises an AttributeError, you’re probably using a version of Django that doesn’t match this tutorial version. You’ll want to either switch to the older tutorial or the newer Django version.

You must run python from the same directory manage.py is in, or ensure that directory is on the Python path, so that import mysite works.

For more information on all of this, see the django-admin documentation.

But how to do `python manage.py <command>` using the `django.setup()` is nowhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [call_command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) to run django manage commands.

Here is an example of using it to call migrate;

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command("migrate", interactive=False)
```

I have `interactive=False` because this runs on a continual integration server - but depending on your usage you may wish to omit it.

Comment: Where should be the created script to be saved? where the manage.py is? or where settings.py is? How would this script come to know that you want to do 'python manage.py migrate'. Do I need to do django.setup() before running your code.?

Comment: On Heliohost I don't have bash, python shell. What I have is running Django App. Can I run Migrate code from django view.py file?

Comment: if you have ftp to the django project files. make a script.py save @Shadow code in a python script. upload the script to myproject/myproject/myapp directory.  Write a view in views.py that calls the python script. update your urls.py to point to the view.   Anytime you access that url it will run your migrate script for you.  (This is not a clean way of running migrate on a host)

Comment: Thanks. I have added that code to views itself. Working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to:

- import your settings
- configure Django with your settings
- setup Django
- call the command

If you have a python shell **and** it is within the python path of your project, once you're inside the shell you could execute the following:

```
>>> from myprojectpath import settings as myapp_defaults
>>> import django
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> if not settings.configured:
        settings.configure(myapp_defaults)
>>> django.setup()
>>> call_command("migrate", interactive=False)
```

hope it helps

Comment: I said I don't have Python console. But I Think I can convert it to script and try to run.

Comment: `if not settings.configured: settings.configure(myapp_defaults)` was not necessary for my case.